# A delegate with different protocol types

Tags: ios, swift, delegation

```
protocol CellActionHandling {
    func didTapOptionButton()
    func didTapEditButton()
    func notActiveViewAction(state: Cell.State)
}
```

So I had a delegate protocol (for a cell) with three methods, it was being implemented by two classes so that those classes can respond to actions. But one class only needed two methods instead of three, so I did interface segregation, now I have two protocols, and one class conforms to both while other just to one.

```
protocol CellActionHandling {
    func didTapOptionButton()
    func didTapEditButton()
}

protocol NotActiveViewActionHandling {
    func notActiveViewAction(state: Cell.State)
}
```

Earlier I had one protocol and was using that as the type of cell's delegate property.

`var delegate: CellActionHandling?`

**Problem:** After interface segregation now I'm not sure what should be the type of delegate property.

`var delegate: ?`

I know about protocol extensions, that way I won't be able to enforce the the conforming classes to provide implementation. And then this won't be any different from what was being done previously.

Would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are two different solutions here. The first solution is that in the Cell class, you have two properties for each of the different delegates. This makes sense if the two different protocols are in fact very different.

```
weak var actionDelegate: CellActionHandling?
weak var nonActiveDelegate: NotActiveViewActionHandling?
```

The other solution that I'd recommend is by combining the two protocols again and making the unused function optional. This makes it so when you are implementing the protocol, you don't actually need to create a function for it. Say for example it is `NotActiveViewActionHandling` that is only being implemented once. Then you can do:

```
@objc protocol CellActionHandling {
    func didTapOptionButton()
    func didTapEditButton()
    @objc optional func notActiveViewAction(state: Cell.State)
}
```

If all these functions make sense in one protocol, then I'd definitely go for the second option. Since you know what `notActiveViewAction` does, you can make the decision about whether they should exist in the same protocol or not.

Comment: Thank you for your time to write back. First solution you provided was in my mind but what if another protocol gets added, I will have to create another delegate. 
Regarding second approach, I can't enforce the implementation of `notActiveViewAction`. Yes one way is adding extension and putting `fatalError` inside it to enforce it's conformance but not sure if that's right.

Comment: I think having multi, differently typed properties (who potentially reference the same thing) is the way to go. Consider how UITableView splits its collaborating objects into `delegate` _and_ `dataSource`

Comment: Anyone else irked that optional protocol conformance requires the objc annotation? I'm guessing the reasoning here is that a protocol is meant to define functionality of something. If it's "optional" for an implementation to even _do_ something, then does that really even mean that functionality should even belong to that protocol?

So yeah, I think splitting them up into two is the way to go. That way, when you do decide a delegate should receive the `notActiveViewAction(state:)` functionality, it can implement that protocol and absolutely respond to that action.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to make two different properties for each protocol because each one has a different task. If you ever and I'm sure you've noticed that either UITableview or UICollectionview, both have two different type of protocols like (UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource) or (UITableviewDelegate and UITableviewDatasource) and you have to implement both or only one if you need it.

```
weak var actionDelegate: CellActionHandling?
weak var cellStateDelegate: NotActiveViewActionHandling?
```